# PHP null use this value

Tags: php, syntax

In c# you can do ?? to check for null and then use a value like so..

```
DateTime? today = null;
DateTime todayNotNull = today ?? Date.Now;
```

Is there a shorthand way to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

```
$var = ConditionalTest ? ValueIfTrue : ValueIfFalse;
```

Note that both `ValueIfTrue` and `ValueIfFalse` must be used.

---

In your specific case:

```
<?php
    $today = null;
    $todayNotNull = isset($today) ? $today : date();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$todayNotNull = ($today===NULL ? date() : $today);
```

---

**UPDATE**: Be careful when using implicit NULL check like `$today ? $today : date()`.

```
true is true. (type: boolean)
false is false. (type: boolean)
null is false. (type: NULL)
[] is false. (type: array)
[0] is true. (type: array)
[1, 2, 3] is true. (type: array)
{1: 2, "x": 3} is true. (type: array)
"" is false. (type: string)
"0" is false. (type: string)
"1" is true. (type: string)
"2" is true. (type: string)
"x" is true. (type: string)
0 is false. (type: integer)
1 is true. (type: integer)
2 is true. (type: integer)
0 is false. (type: double)
0.1 is true. (type: double)
0.2 is true. (type: double)
```

I rather urge you to explicitly test for NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Ternary operator as indicated by other users.

```
$today = null;
$todayNotNull = $today ? $today : time();
```

As of PHP 5.3, you can also shorten this to the familiar syntax you want:

```
$todayNotNull = $today ?: time();
```

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the
>   ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1
>   evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.